# How can I overcome with this issue in React Native Expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, build-error, eas

eas build -p android
√ Generated eas.json
√ Using remote Android credentials (Expo server)
√ Using Keystore from configuration: Build Credentials XRjgxG6sJK (default)

Compressing project files and uploading to EAS Build. Learn more: https://expo.fyi/eas-build-archive
√ Compressed project files 5s (6.9 MB)
√ Uploaded to EAS 2s

Build details: https://expo.dev/accounts/abdul_wahid/projects/Gym/builds/4898e396-8a48-4172-88b0-ce635cf4ac6c

Waiting for build to complete. You can press Ctrl+C to exit.
× Build failed

Android build failed:
Unknown error. See logs for more information.

Expecting the solution

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not likely you will get any answers with this little information. Did you check the logs like the error says to do? Post the logs so someone can help. Check out [ask] when you can.